# Read Text File with stream reader

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

I want to read a text file that has 3 lines of data one line contains "Server = ..." The next line is "Username = .. " and the last line is "Password = ... " So I want to read this file and put each line into a separate label.. (label1,label2,label3)

OFDSet is my openfiledialog

All in Visual Basic..

Some one help?

Here is the code I tried but I get an error:

```
Dim oReader As StreamReader

        If OFDSet.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            oReader = New StreamReader(OFDSet.FileName, True)
            ServLabel.Text = oReader.ReadLine(1)
            UserLabel.Text = oReader.ReadLine(2)
            PassLabel.Text = oReader.ReadLine(3)

        End If
```

Comment: and the error would be....?

Comment: and why dont you try reading the documentation:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx

Comment: NullReference Exception was unhandled it circles the

Comment: ServLabel.Text = oReader.ReadLine(1)
UserLabel.Text = oReader.ReadLine(2)
PassLabel.Text = oReader.ReadLine(3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler solution is through the File.ReadAllLines method that gives back an array of strings with just one call.

```
If OFDSet.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(OFDSet.FileName)
    ServLabel.Text = lines(0)
    UserLabel.Text = lines(1)
    PassLabel.Text = lines(2)
End If
```

[See the MSDN reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

(File class needs an imports for System.IO)

Also if your first line is something like this

```
Server=MyServerPC
```

and you want only the part `MyServerPC` in the ServLabel you need to split the input at the `=` sign

```
ServLabel.Text = lines(0).Split("="c)(1)
```

Of course this is just an example. More robust error handling is needed. You should check if you have at least 3 lines and if each line is correctly separated by the `=` sign.

Comment: I use it and i get error? "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Comment: Do you have at least 3 lines in the selected file? If you set a breakpoint on the first assignement, how many lines are contained in the array `lines`?

Answer (score 1):

`StreamReader.ReadLine()` has no overload that takes a parameter.  Intellisense will show you two overloads because the return type, `String`, has an indexer.